# Get with Home Assistant API from Google script causes error

Tags: google-apps-script, home-assistant

I'm trying to query my Home Assistant, pull the value of a sensor and write it to a google drive sheet. With Postman no problem, so url and token are correct. It doesn't work with google script. I'm only writing the part of the code that performs the GET with the Home Assistant API, I've removed the one that writes in the google sheet that.

```
function fetchHomeAssistantData() {
  var url = "https://myurl:8123/api/states/sensor.produzione_max_oggi";
  var token = "myapikey";

var options = {
"method": "GET",
"headers": {
"Authorization": "Bearer " + token
},
"muteHttpExceptions": true
};

var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
var data = response.getContentText();
var jsonData = JSON.parse(data);

Logger.log(options);
Logger.log(response.getContentText()); // Stampa la risposta completa nel log
var state = jsonData.state;
var lastChanged = jsonData.last_changed;
}
```

Response: "*Error   SyntaxError: Unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON at position 3
fetchHomeAssistantData  @ HARestApi.gs:15*"
any help please?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, your question seems to be in Italian. Please be aware that [English is required for all content on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/non-english-questions)

Comment: I couldn't find many questions that pertain to Home Assistant API and in my case I don't have any smart devices to communicate with.  You might wish to try [Google Apps Script Community](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/google-apps-script-community)

Comment: hI, the log is "Error 
SyntaxError: Unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON at position 3
fetchHomeAssistantData @ HARestApi.gs:17"  were you referring to something else?